# JavaScript - Rand without repetitions with tmp array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Since two days I have a problem with arrays and conditions in JavaScript. 
Could you check my code and give me suggestions what should I correct to run this code without infinite loop?

The list of steps (to clarify my problem) - how this code should work:
 1. starting the draw
 2. Get random quote -> `quote[r_quote]` where `r_quote` is random number
 3. If the `tmp` array is empty, add drawn quote into `tmp[j]`
 4. Get next random quote (step 2)
 5. If the `tmp` is not empty
 6. Compare all `tmp` elements with the new, random quote
 7. If the new random quote is unique, add it to `tmp[j]`

**I've currently problem with step 7. When this part of code is uncommented, the loop begins to be processed infinity.**

```js
var quote = new Array();
quote[0] = 'AAAAAAAAAA';
quote[1] = 'Lorem ipsum.';
quote[2] = 'BBBBBBBBBB';
quote[3] = 'CCCCCCCCCC';

var numberOfQoutes = quote.length;
var r_quote;

var tmp = new Array();
var j = 0;

console.log("start... ");
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  r_quote = Math.floor(numberOfQoutes * Math.random());
  console.log('[Step ' + i + '] \t\nquote[' + r_quote + ']' + ' => ' + quote[r_quote]);

  if(tmp.length == 0) {
   console.log('\ttmp array is empty. You can append ANY quote.');
   
   tmp[j] = quote[r_quote];
 console.log('\t\tAppended: ' + tmp[j]);
 console.log(j); // show current tmp array position
   j++;
  } else {
   // add just unique qoute 
 console.log('\ttmp array is not empty.');
 console.log('\tChecking if drawn quotation has already been appended.')
    
  for(k = 0; k < tmp.length; k++) {
   console.log("\tk=" + k + "\t" + tmp[k] + "\t<< comparing >>\t" + quote[r_quote]);
     
   if(tmp[k] !== quote[r_quote]) { // this if probably doesn't work
      console.log("\t\t[OK] You can append quote.");
    console.log(j); // show current tmp array position
    console.log('\t\tAssign this quote[' + r_quote + '] => ' + quote[r_quote]);
      console.log('\t\tInto tmp[' + j + ']');
     
    /* what's wrong here?
       tmp[j] = quote[r_quote]; // I want to add random qoute to new position in array
       console.log("Appended: " + tmp[j]);
       console.log(k);
       j++;
    */
    }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: A simple algorithm is to copy the original array, then randomly [*splice*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.splice) members from it to *tmp* so they are added in random order with no duplicates.

Comment: @hindmost When I remove the comment `/* what's wrong here? ... */` the loop is infinity. I don't know why. As you can see, two lines above I peeping logs in console to check the current `tmp` position and the qoute that I'm going to add to `tmp[j]` position.  
@RobG my code works but just without the part which is currently in comment and I'm looking for causes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that here:

```
for(k = 0; k < tmp.length; k++) {
```

you check whether k < tmp.length, and here:

```
tmp[j] = quote[r_quote];
j++;
```

you always add another element to the array, so it's length keeps climbing until you run out of memory

Comment: Thank you :) that was so easy... Now, the loop works but there are not always unique elements in tmp. For example, last try `Array [ "CCCCCCCCCC", "BBBBBBBBBB", "BBBBBBBBBB" ]` <- 2x BBBBBBBBBB. I noticed that when I change condiion to `if(tmp[k] != quote[r_quote])` it works correctly. But I wonder why `!==` doesn't work 
because what I know, it checks also the type and is more restrictive.